# bootstrap 4 grid system issue

Tags: bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4, grid-system

**`table-> tr> td`** is almost equivalent to **`container-fluid-> row-> col-* or col-*-*`**

My problem  is very simple but maybe I don't know how bootstrap 4 grid system works.

Let's look at my below problem,

I want to group three elements by wrapping them in an outer `div` under `div class=row` as shown below and it should result in working part demo example. *(Please ignore my custom css class for time being)*

So the problem is when I take outer div, it just messes up the layout.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
       <div class="col-12"> <!-- here ---- i tried class="col-12 or col-md-12 -->

          <h2 class="curriculum-vitae col-md-6 text-right">Text1</h2>
          <h2 class="resume-name col-md-6 text-left">text2</h2>
          <h6 class="resume-address text-center col-md-12">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</h6>

        </div>


        <div class="col-12"> <!-- i tried class="col-12 or col-md-12" -->

           <div class="col-md-5 text-right resume-mobile"><i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;<span>abcde</span></div>
           <div class="col-md-2 text-center resume-mobile"><i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;<span>abcde</span></div>
           <div class="col-md-5 text-left resume-email"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;<a href="">abcde</a></div>

        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Without outer div, it looks and works perfectly fine.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

            <h2 class="curriculum-vitae col-md-6 text-right">Text1</h2>
            <h2 class="resume-name col-md-6 text-left">text2</h2>
            <h6 class="resume-address text-center col-md-12">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</h6>


            <div class="col-md-5 text-right resume-mobile"><i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;<span>abcde</span></div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-center resume-mobile"><i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;<span>abcde</span></div>
            <div class="col-md-5 text-left resume-email"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;<a href="">abcde</a></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Reproduction of the problem (Just maximize the output window to get the exact result)

**https://plnkr.co/edit/fk0uO3Z9fR1EVEc79Xb3?p=preview**

Answer (score 0):

First off, you're loading your style.css before bootstrap.css instead of after -- you should load your theming after bootstrap so as to properly override. Secondly you're not including the bootstrap js in the footer, so you will not benefit from any of the enhanced bootstrap functionality.

But to answer your question, the 'working' example above is because you're doing it correctly. You don't need the col-12 wrapper around the sections like you think you do, and if you DO want that, then you need to nest another internal class="row" inside it, wrapping the inner content.

See "Nesting": http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#nesting